# In iOS 7, with customer VC transitioning, is it possible to make "fromviewcontroller" on screen after presentViewController?

Tags: ios, ios7, presentviewcontroller, custom-transition

Many apps have the feature which, user can pull down one view, and another view shows up from underneath it. But the first view is still visible on the bottom. (e.g. Facebook Paper App).

If the other view is from another view controller, is it possible to achieve this by using iOS 7's custom view controller transitioning API ?

In my test, it is possible to do the "presenting" part, but the "dismissing" part has a glitch. Whenever we call dismissViewController, the "toViewController" takes over the full screen even before calling the transitioningDelegate methods.

Anyone more familiar with this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

> If the other view is from another view controller, is it possible to achieve this by using iOS 7's custom view controller transitioning API ?

Yes, it's possible. You can use the snapshot API to take a snapshot of any UIView. With this you can take a snapshot of view controller you're transitioning from, then add it to the `containerView` below the view controller you're transitioning to.

For example, in the `-animateTransition:` method of your class that adopts `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` take a snapshot of the view controller you're transitioning from and add it as a subview beneath the view controller you're transitioning to:

```
- (void)animateTransition:(id <UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    UIView * containerView = transitionContext.containerView;
    UIViewController *fromViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    UIViewController *toViewController = [transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    // take snapshot of from view controller
    UIView * fromSnapshotView = [fromViewController.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
    [containerView insertSubview:fromSnapshotView belowSubview:toViewController.view];

    // Then do your animations on the to view controller to animate it into view as well as the fromSnapshotView

    // Finally, don't forget to call:
    [transitionContext completeTransition:![transitionContext transitionWasCancelled]];
}
```

> In my test, it is possible to do the "presenting" part, but the "dismissing" part has a glitch. Whenever we call dismissViewController, the "toViewController" takes over the full screen even before calling the transitioningDelegate methods.

If your call to dismiss doesn't fire your transitioning delegate methods make sure that you set the transitioning delegate on that view controller before dismissing.

Comment: I had to use this method. Otherwise I had the same problems described above. This feels like a bug to me. Hopefully, Apple addresses it in the future.